# Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives in VueApp

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This error comes up:

```
[vue/require-v-for-key]
Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.
```

Codepen - https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-pine-8u9mt?file=/src/components/Laptops.vue:386-393

Does anybody know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When using `v-for`, vue expects a unique key for each iteration. You can achieve this by binding an index key to your div element

```
 <div v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">
   // code to execute
 </div>
```

`:key` is shorthand for `v-bind:key`

Comment: im not sure what you mean

Comment: I have an another question i want to display total in cart model ,but i am not able to do so it displayed "Nan" in total section , can you please take a look at this codepen -https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-pine-8u9mt?file=/src/main.js

Comment: sorry, i cant seem to find the code that you are referencing. NaN means not a number so maybe your total is actually a string and you need to convert it to an integer first. you could check the type with typeof() and if its a string you just need to use the parseInt() function

Comment: As @Jesse stated , there is no references of where NaN might come , also your Cart.vue is not implemented though in given link which possibly you are referred